# How to interact with another SVG after clicking a SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

In my code, I have an SVG of the USA. The USA SVG has paths for every US State. Once one clicks on a specific US State, the ID of that path matches with another SVG (an enlarged State SVG) that is in a separate folder called "counties". The USA SVG fades out, and the enlarged State SVG fades in. How, then, can I interact with this newly shown enlarged state SVG?

Here is my code that grabs the enlarged State SVG after clicking on a specific path on the USA SVG:

```
  <object style="width:auto; height:auto;" id="countyLevel" data="" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

and the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('path').on("click",function(e){
   var state = "counties/"+$(this).attr('id') + ".svg";
     showState(state);
    });  
 }); 

function showState(stateFile) {
    $('.usa').fadeOut();
    $('.returncountry').fadeIn();
    $('.table2').fadeIn();
    $("#countyLevel").attr("data", stateFile);  
    $("#countyLevel").css('display', 'block');
  }
```

The paths on the USA SVG are interactive, but I don't know how to make the new enlarged State SVG paths interactive once it fades in.

Comment: "interactive" is a pretty broad term. What exactly do you have in mind?

Comment: @ccprog I want to just be able to click a path on the enlarged state and have an alert come up. If i can do that, then I can figure everything else out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the DOM of a document in an `<object>` tag with `.contentDocument` as soon as one is loaded. From there you can select nodes like you would in any other document:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('path').on("click",function(e){
    var state = "counties/"+$(this).attr('id') + ".svg";
        showState(state);
    });  
    // queue up the load event once
    $("#countyLevel").on("load", function () {
        // choose adequate selectors and events
        $(this.contentDocument).find('path').on("click", showAlert);
    });
});

// showState as above
// showAlert defines your interaction
```

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I should have mentioned you have to wait for loading. See edit.

Comment: so i put it above the $("#countyLevel").attr("data", stateFile); that i already have? I did that and it is giving me an error "Unexpected token ')'

Comment: My example is no executable code. Exchange `function ...` for a callback that defines your interaction.

Comment: I rewrote the example to show how you can attach the `load` event handler once, so that every time the county map is exchanged, the inner `click` event is re-activated.